# Почему ExeptionHandler в NestJS в stackTrace не указывает на клиентский код?

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch, nestjs, typeorm

Возник вопрос по поводу скудности информации при возникновении exception в приложении.
Ситуация следующая, возникла ошибка добавления данных в базу, т.к. одно из полей в базе имеет constraint  not null на поле, а то что мы пытались добавить оказалось null и база ругнулась.

Exception был перехвачен ExceptionHandler'ом фреймворка NestJS но в итоговом stacktrace почему то не оказалось указания на наш клиентский код, который вызвал библиотечную функцию, а только на код самой библиотечной функции, прилагаю скрин логов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из скрина логов можно сделать вывод что exeption случился в библиотеке TypeORM но какой клиентский код вызвал эту библиотечную функцию из логов увы мы понять не можем....

Как вы думаете как можно решить данную проблему не оборачивая каждую строчку кода в try/catch ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покурив документацию к гнезду(nestjs) я понял как можно решить проблему: необходимо написать глобальный exceptionFilter который будет перехватывать все неперехваченные эксепшены и выводить более детальную информацию о проблеме.

Конечно точную точку входа во внешнюю библиотеку где случился exception это не позволяет определить, но если наше приложени что то вроде rest api то мы по крайней мере сможем понять по какому route пришёл злополучный запрос:

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost } from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch()
export class AllExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    console.log('EXCEPTION DATA:');
    console.log(exception);

    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();

    console.log('CONTEXT:');
    console.log(ctx);
  }
}
```

Если будете использовать данный совет то не забывайте подключить это фильтр глобально:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AllExceptionsFilter } from './exception.filter';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter()); // <---------

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Для справки привожу тот участок документации который позволил написать вышеприведенный код:

https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters